# Spock testing exception handling in a Where block

Tags: exception, groovy, spock, data-driven-tests

I am testing a service method which has a few dependencies; and I want to assert that if any of these dependencies throws an exception, the service method should return a default value.

The service and the test I'd like to write look something like this.

```
static class Service {
    def dependency1
    def dependency2
    def dependency3

    def method() {
        try {
            def foo = dependency1.get()
            def bar = dependency2.get()
            def baz = dependency3.get()
            return " $foo $bar $baz "
        } catch (Exception e) {
            println e
            return ' default value '
        }
    }
}

def 'test Service error handling'() {
    given:
    def dependency1 = Mock(Supplier)
    def dependency2 = Mock(Supplier)
    def dependency3 = Mock(Supplier)
    def serviceUnderTest = new Service(dependency1: dependency1, dependency2: dependency2, dependency3: dependency3)

    when:
    def result = serviceUnderTest.method()

    then:
    result == ' default value '
    dependency1.get() >> closure1
    dependency2.get() >> closure2
    dependency3.get() >> closure3

    where:
    closure1                              | closure2                              | closure3
    {-> throw new Exception('closure1') } | {-> null }                            | {-> null };
    {-> null}                             | {-> throw new Exception('closure2') } | {-> null };
    {-> null}                             | {-> null}                             | {-> throw new Exception('closure3') }
}
```

This test doesn't work, because it causes the mocks to return literal closures rather than the results of those closures. Of course this is caused by the addition of the `where` block, as any mock can directly return the result of a single closure, i.e. `dependency1.get() >> { throw new Exception() }`

Am I forced to write this as three separate tests, or is there another way I can combine them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write

```groovy
dependency1.get() >> closure1
```

your mock will return the closure itself and not evaluate it. The evaluation only happens inside the GroovyString `" $foo $bar $baz "`, expanding the error message happening during evaluation into it but not escalating that exception.

You want to use

```groovy
dependency1.get() >> { closure1() }
```

in order to fix your test. The `()` evaluates your closure, but at the same time the surrounding closure `{}` makes sure that the evaluation happens only when the stub method is called, not already when it is defined.

A few improvement ideas:

- How about unrolling your test, splitting it into multiple methods with parametrised names? This also has the nice side effect to help the IDE and Groovy compiler parse your `where:` block without semicolons and `{ -> ...` syntax.
- How about stubbing the mock methods in the `given:` block instead of in the `then:` block where they don't belong?
- How about stubbing the methods inside the mock definition to make the test more compact?
- How about replacing the `when: ... then:` in this simple case by `expect:` as the Spock manual suggests?

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q57172322

import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class ServiceDependenciesThrowingErrorsTest extends Specification {

  @Unroll
  def 'handle error in service #serviceName'() {
    given:
    def serviceUnderTest = new Service(
      dependency1: Mock(Supplier) { get() >> { closure1() } },
      dependency2: Mock(Supplier) { get() >> { closure2() } },
      dependency3: Mock(Supplier) { get() >> { closure3() } }
    )

    expect:
    serviceUnderTest.method() == 'default value'

    where:
    serviceName | closure1                            | closure2                            | closure3
    "A"         | { throw new Exception('closure1') } | { null }                            | { null }
    "B"         | { null }                            | { throw new Exception('closure2') } | { null }
    "C"         | { null }                            | { null }                            | { throw new Exception('closure3') }
  }

  static class Service {
    def dependency1
    def dependency2
    def dependency3

    def method() {
      try {
        def foo = dependency1.get()
        def bar = dependency2.get()
        def baz = dependency3.get()
        return "$foo $bar $baz"
      } catch (Exception e) {
        println e
        return 'default value'
      }
    }
  }

  static class Supplier {
    def get() {
      "OK"
    }
  }

}
```

This is what the test execution looks like in my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) when unrolled:

[image: Unrolled test execution in IntelliJ IDEA]