# How to use jmockit in Spock to test static methods to return multiple different values?

Tags: spock, jmockit

I want to use jmockit to test the static method in Spock, and combine the where tag to achieve different values of each mock to test different business logic. I tried a lot of writing methods, but they all failed. I hope I can get help or suggestions here. Thank you very much

Here is an example of my business code:

```java
public class MyUtils {
    public static int staticMethod(int origin) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

```java
public class MyClass {    
    public void verify(int origin) {
        if (MyUtils.staticMethod(origin) == 1) {
            System.out.println("1");
        }
        if (MyUtils.staticMethod(origin) == 2) {
            System.out.println("2");
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

This is my Spock test code：

```java
def "verify"() {
    when:
    myClass.verify(0)

    then:
    true

    where:
    mock | _
    mockStatic(1) | _
    mockStatic(2) | _
}

def mockStatic(val){
    new MockUp<MyUtils>() {
        @Mock
        public int staticMethod(int origin) {
            return val
        }
    }
}
```

I know that power can implement such a function, but because our team has been using jmockit, we want to know whether jmockit can implement such multiple different values of mock in Spock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your method call into a closure and evaluate the closure during each iteration:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q67882559

import mockit.Mock
import mockit.MockUp
import mockit.internal.state.SavePoint
import spock.lang.Requires
import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class StaticMethodJMockitTest extends Specification {
  def jMockitSavePoint = new SavePoint()

  def cleanup() {
    jMockitSavePoint.rollback()
  }

  @Unroll
  def "verify"() {
    given:
    mockClosure()
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass()

    when:
    myClass.verify(0)

    then:
    true

    where:
    mockClosure << [
      { /* no mock */ },
      { mockStatic(1) },
      { mockStatic(2) }
    ]
  }

  def mockStatic(val) {
    new MockUp<MyUtils>() {
      @Mock
      int staticMethod(int origin) {
        return val
      }
    }
  }

  public static class MyUtils {
    public static int staticMethod(int origin) {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  public static class MyClass {
    public void verify(int origin) {
      if (MyUtils.staticMethod(origin) == 1) {
        System.out.println("1");
      }
      if (MyUtils.staticMethod(origin) == 2) {
        System.out.println("2");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you wish to use data tables, you need to help the parser a bit by explicitly adding `it ->`  inside in the closure, if the closure is in the first column of the data table. You can also use some nice naming for your unrolled iterations:

```java
  @Unroll
  def "verify #description"() {
    given:
    mockClosure()
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass()

    when:
    myClass.verify(0)

    then:
    true

    where:
    description     | mockClosure
    "no mock"       | { /* no mock */ }
    "mock result 1" | { mockStatic(1) }
    "mock result 2" | { mockStatic(2) }
  }
```

The reason for creating and rolling back the save point is that JMockit does not play nice with Spock concerning mock lifecycles and the maintainer has no intention to even think about helping. See [JMockit issue #668](https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/668#issuecomment-614426955) for more info.

Comment: Yes, closure can solve this problem. I see you are in another scenario（ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57172322/spock-testing-exception-handling-in-a-where-block ）We also use the method of closure. Thank you very much for your answer！! kriegaex

Comment: As for closures: It seems you love to put logic into your `where:` blocks. So maybe this is why we end up using closures again.